# How to remove topic torch from my computer?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, malware, malware-removal

Somehow I have managed to get the topic torch malware installed on my computer, which show's ads whenever browsing (see screenshot).

[image: http://imgur.com/p4U0gV7]

I have many of suggestions, but I can't seem to find the programs associated with the malware (webcake, yontoo or any associated programs or any unusual extensions in chrome) installed.

I've also tried a couple of free malware scanners with no luck.

Any help would be great. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does an adblocker remove it?

Comment: @magicandre1981 An ad blocker is no solution here. You might be able to hide the symtpoms but not the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is just another "bundled offer" included in some installers, especially things such as some "free whatever downloader" and similar "crapware".

First of all, what happens if you boot to safe mode? Does it still show up? If not, this will most likely be the best base/start to remove this.

Look under **Add/Remove Programs** and see whether you can find any entry mentioning **Yontoo**. If you do, remove it and all other entries you don't recognize that got installed at the same date (you can sort the entries).

Once that's done, download the free version of [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/), install it and let it run.

If that's done, check your browser for any remaining addons you don't recognize. If you don't and the banners no longer appear, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I will try safe boot mode. I certainly can't see any entries for Yontoo otherwise.

Comment: Just look for any other entries that got installed recently (around the time you noticed the banners popping up). Some installers will run delayed to make sure users don't kill the task in case they notice that they forgot to untick something.

Comment: You seem to have breezed right past that recommendation to use Malawarebytes (aka "superantispyware").  However, it's generally the most effective tool to use against this kind of exploit.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft offers Windows Defender Offline (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-windows-defender-offline) which basically makes sure that your computer is not affected. Some viruses like these may decide to "hide" or disable the software used to find these viruses, which is what you may be experiencing. Microsoft recommends downloading the software in an uninfected computer so that the virus will not interfere with the process. Simply insert the burned disc into your computer and press a key at startup to boot using the CD/DVD. Also, it may also be the websites itself or the browser which is infected. Do check before you do the mentioned above.

Comment: Its definitely the computer, and just a browser or site as this happens across a number of breweries and almost all sites. I've tried Windows scanner are there any other options?

Comment: There are some other options that I dosen't come to mind now, but I think it's still best to go with Windows Scanner. Have you tried burning the disc at a friend's computer or have you used your own? And you say the ads pop up only during browsing, I assume, not any other place. You may want to try using IE or Firefox to see if it fixes the problem. If it dosen't, well, it is your computer. If it's ok, it's probably Chrome, which a simple reinstall should fix.

Comment: I installed Windows scanner the same way as you suggested and it didn't find anything. I am getting the ads across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I use Acronis True image to backup my operating system to avoid effort for removing this kind of
malware.

I use 2 operating systems Vista 64 or windows 7 64 and windows XP in another partion so if I have problem with one of them ,, I use the other with search facility to remove all what is related to this kind of malware ,, also there is malware killer program but it is of no use in thede cases ,, I don't know if this an answer or not but this what I use for my self ...